# Upload image to database return null or error

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

For several hours I have been trying to write a code that would allow uploading photos to the database, but either nothing is added to the database or it causes an error:

> The [filename] value is not valid

My **Restauracja.cs** file:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Wybierz plik")]
[MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "vxvxcvcxvxxx")]
[Display(Name = "Zdjecia")]
public string LinkZdjecia { get; set; }

[Display(Name = "Zdjecia")]
public byte[] Photo { get; set; }
```

Controller **RestauracjaController.cs**:

```
public class RestauracjaController : Controller
{
    private readonly FirmaContext _context;

    public RestauracjaController(FirmaContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

   public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Restauracja restauracja, List<IFormFile> Photo)
    {
        foreach (var item in Photo)
        {
            if (item.Length > 0)
            {
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await item.CopyToAsync(stream);
                    restauracja.Photo = stream.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }

        return View(restauracja);
    }
}
```

View **Create.cs**:

```
<form asp-action="Create">
  <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="LinkZdjecia" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="LinkZdjecia" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="LinkZdjecia" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Photo" class="control-label"></label>
                <input name="Image" id="Imageinput" class="form-control" type="file" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Photo" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
</form>
```

In this case, I got error:

> The [filename] value is not valid

In second case, to database is saved `null` (in Photo). Controller **RestauracjaController.cs**:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Restauracja restauracja, IFormFile Image)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Image.CopyTo(ms);
                restauracja.Photo = ms.ToArray();
            }

            _context.Add(restauracja);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
        return View(restauracja);
    }
```

Comment: This question sounds like, "here is all my code, what is wrong?". Please, concentrate on a specific piece that caused error.

Comment: I create breakopint and Create method in Controller and Photo is null. But i don't know why

Comment: <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post"

Comment: @JohnMeek thanks, it fix my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
public class RestauracjaController : Controller
{
    private readonly FirmaContext _context;

    public RestauracjaController(FirmaContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

   public async Task<IActionResult> Create(Restauracja restauracja, List<IFormFile> Photo)
    {
        foreach (var item in Photo)
        {
            if (item.Length > 0)
            {
                byte[] result = null;
                using (var readStream = item.OpenReadStream())
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    readStream.CopyTo(stream);
                    result = readStream.ToArray();

                    //restauracja.Photo = result;
                    //_context.Add(restauracja);
                }
            }
        }

        return View(restauracja);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Like @T.S. said in the first comment to your question, your code has a lot of potential issues, so it's hard to answer without having to do a full code review which is out of scope on SO. Here are some issues I can see:

1. the type of `Photo` should be `IFormFile` not `byte[]`.
2. Why does the `Create` action take a second parameter `List<IFormFile> Photo`? If you want multiple images, then change make `Restauracja.Photo` as `IEnumerable<IFormFile>`, and remove the second parameter in `Create`. But for now, start with one image, make it work, and then try changing it to multiple images.
3. Why did you give the `input` the name `Image`? There is no such a property in the model. Change it to `Photo` and use tag helper.

Like this:

```
<input asp-for="Photo" class="form-control" />
```

There are other issues, but the above ones will get you going.

Comment: Can i create in database Photo type IFormFile ?

Comment: No, the model `Restauracja` is for the view, not the database. The `IFormFile` is used to upload the file to the server. Then the `Create` action takes the `IFormFile` and converts it to a byte array for saving in the database. Do not use view models directly with the database because views have different requirements and needs from the database. So you need another model for the database, and in the `Create` action,  you convert the `Restauracja` model to the database model which you then pass to `_context`.